# Trying to figure out a problem with async returning an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

For some reason my .then() gives me just an observable when I console log it out, is there a way to get the data that it's returning?

I've tried a bunch of different ways to solve my issue with async/await but I can't seem to grasp what to do. Right now it seems my page is loading and then my data is coming through with causes an error to get thrown in the console. The data eventually comes through but not before the error gets thrown.

This is my component ts:

```js
async getGames() {
    await this.games.getAllGames(this.currentPage).then(game => {
      this.gamesArray = game;
    });
}
```

This is from my service file

```js
async getAllGames(page) {
    console.log('11111111111111');
    const queryParams = `?page=${page}`;
    return await this.http.get(this.url + queryParams);
}
```

This is my html

```html
<div class="col-lg-9 float-right">
    <!-- <div *ngIf='loading'  class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="spinner-border" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status"></div>
    </div> -->
    <!-- <div *ngIf="!loading"> -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 card-background" *ngFor="let game of gamesArray.games">
            <div class="card-surround shadow-sm">
                <div>
                    <h2>{{game.homeTeam.teamName}}</h2>
                    <h2>{{game.awayTeam.teamName}}</h2>
                    <canvas id="{{game.id}}"></canvas>
                    <hr>
                    <p>{{game.gameTime}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- </div> -->
    <ngb-pagination class="d-flex justify-content-end" 
        size="sm" 
        [collectionSize]="gamesArray.games.length" 
        [(page)]="currentPage"
        [maxSize]="5" 
        [pageSize]='6'                  
        [rotate]="true" 
        [ellipses]="false"
        [boundaryLinks]="true"
        (pageChange)='onPageChange($event)'>
    </ngb-pagination>
</div>
```

The problem is the game in the then() is returning an observable and not the data that I'm expecting to get back from the server/database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that angular `http.get()` returns an Observable, so in your `getAllGames()` function when you say:

`return await this.http.get(this.url + queryParams)`;

You are actually returning an Observable instead of a Promise. It should be something like:

`return await this.http.get(this.url + queryParams).toPromise()`;

Also in the  `getGames(`) function, if you use await then you shouldn't be using the promise `then()` method. Instead it should be something like:

```
async getGames() {    
    const game = await this.games.getAllGames(this.currentPage);
    this.gamesArray = game;
  }
```

Comment: So that does indeed return the games but for some reason I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Did you made the changes I suggested? Specifically to add .toPromise() after this.http.get(this.url + queryParams)

Comment: Yes, and it's working, now I just have to figure out my chart.js problem haha, it's never ending.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @alexortizl, you just need to call `toPromise()` on `getAllGames()` return value and it would work.

```
async getAllGames(page) {
      console.log('11111111111111');
      const queryParams = `?page=${page}`;
      return await this.http.get(this.url + queryParams).toPromise(); // <--- like this
    }
```

I'd just like to add that you could just as well, use the observable itself from calling `this.http.get(...)`. You'd just need to call `subscribe` instead of `then`.

Take a look at this stackblitz proj to see how the code would look like.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7bh6e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgame.service.ts